# I need to update my DrawerLayout from fragment on Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a function on my MainActivity to load the user data from Firestore to update my image on the drawer, but it is only updating when I restart the app, when I update the users details on the profile fragment, the details are updated on Firebase but not on my drawer. How can I change this? The tutorial I'm using do everything in different activities.

Below is my function on main activity and the methods on the FirestoreClass

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
 
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        FirestoreClass().loadUserData(this)

   fun updateNavigationUserDetails(user: User){

        val ivDrawerImage : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.iv_drawer)

        Glide
            .with(this)
            .load(user.image)
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user_place_holder)
            .into(ivDrawerImage)

        val userName : TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_drawer)
        userName.text = user.name
        val userEmail : TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_email_drawer)
        userEmail.text = user.email
    }
}
```

```
class FirestoreClass {


    fun loadUserDataOnProfile(fragment: Fragment) {
        firestore.collection(Constants.USERS)
            .document(getCurrentUserID())
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                val loggedUser = document.toObject(User::class.java)

                when(fragment) {
                    is ProfileFragment -> {
                        fragment.setUserDataInUI(loggedUser!!)
                     }
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.e("TAG", "Error ssssss", e)

            }
    }

    fun loadUserData(activity: Activity) {
        firestore.collection(Constants.USERS)
            .document(getCurrentUserID())
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                val loggedUser = document.toObject(User::class.java)

                when (activity) {
                    is SignInActivity -> {
                        activity.signInSuccess(loggedUser!!)
                    }
                    is MainActivity -> {
                        activity.updateNavigationUserDetails(loggedUser!!)
                    }
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.e("TAG", "Error signing in", e)

            }
    }
```

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {

val btnUpdate: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_update)
        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener {
            if(selectedImageUri != null){
                uploadUserImage()
            } else {
                updateUserProfileData()
            }
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_my_profile_to_nav_home)
        }
```

I want to call updateNavigationUserDetails() that is on MainActivity when I press the updateButton on profileFragment. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

first you should create a `NavigationUpdaterListener` interface:

```kotlin
interface NavigationUpdaterListener {
    fun onUserDataChanged()
}
```

then you should make your `MainActivity` implement this interface:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationUpdaterListener {
 
   fun updateNavigationUserDetails(user: User){

        val ivDrawerImage : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.iv_drawer)

        Glide
            .with(this)
            .load(user.image)
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user_place_holder)
            .into(ivDrawerImage)

        val userName : TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_drawer)
        userName.text = user.name
        val userEmail : TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_email_drawer)
        userEmail.text = user.email
    }

    override fun onUserDataChanged() {
        updateNavigationUserDetails()
    }
}
```

then you can invoke the listener from your `ProfileFragment` like this:

```kotlin
(requireActivity() as NavigationUpdaterListener).onUserDataChanged()
```

Comment: But how can I get the user to call updateNavigationUserDetails() inside onUserDataChanged()? I updated the MainActivity with the invoke of loadUserData from FirestoreClass

Answer (score 0):

Update:

The part where you update the user data, for example :

```
mFirebaseFirestore
  .collection("users")
  .document(mFirebaseAuth.getUid())
  .update(userMap)
  .addOnSuccessListener { document->
     Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!")
     val user = document.toObject(User::class.java)
     //Can be called here
     updateNavigationUserDetails(user)
      }
  .addOnFailureListener {
     Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot failed to update!") }
```

Comment: I tried both ways but I don't know how I get the arguments to pass on them

Comment: Check the updated answer. Hope that helps!

Comment: if you haven't got it yet, please check the updated answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I was loosing a lot of time in this and decided to move along and pick this up later. I tried the updated method. WIthin the .update() on firestore I can't call document.toObject(), apparently only within .get(). I tried nesting a new firestore.collection.document.get inside addOnSuccessListener but it also didn't work

Comment: Oh! There must be some event trigger when data is updated right? Check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)

Comment: That is it! When I update my profile page, the drawer should be updated as well with the information. The way it is now it only updates when I restart the app. Is there a guide to do it in Kotlin?